# How do "Kummer closures" of fields look?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, galois-theory, class-field-theory, kummer-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $A$ a finite abelian group. You can ask: does the regular representation $F[A]$ of $A$ split as a direct sum of 1-dimensional representations? This is equivalent to the following question. Write $(-)^\vee = \hom(-, F^\times)$ for the dual abelian group; then the question is whether the canonical map $A \to A^{\vee\vee}$ is an isomorphism. From the classification of finite abelian groups, you can reduce the question further. Let $\exp(A)$ denote the [exponent](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exponent+of+a+group) of $A$; then we are asking whether $F$ admits $\exp(A)$ distinct $\exp(A)$th roots of unity. Let me slightly abusively call this "$F$ contains an $\exp(A)$th root of unity", i.e. it contains a primitive root other than $1$ (which happens when $\exp(A)$ is a power of the characteristic of $F$).

When the answer to these equivalent questions is "yes", then more generally you get to identify the symmetric monoidal categories of representations of $A$ and of $A^\vee$-graded vector spaces. This matters for example when studying $A$-Galois extensions. If $F$ does contain a primitive $\exp(A)$th root of unity, then $A$-Galois extensions of $F$ are  $A^\vee$-graded algebras, and in fact [twisted group algebras](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+algebra#OfCentralExtensionsAndTwistedGroupAlgebras), and so admit a cohomological classification. This is the basis of [Kummer theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer_theory). In general, an $A$-Galois extension of $F$ is called *Kummer* when $F$ contains a primitive $\exp(A)$th root of unity.

The equation to be a primitive $n$th root has degree $<n$. This implies that if $F$ has characteristic $0$, then the universal abelian extension $F^{\mathrm{ab}}$ of $F$ is *iterated Kummer*, i.e. a composition of Kummer extensions. Indeed: you show by induction that the cyclotomic extension $F \to F^{\mathrm{cyc}}$ is iterated Kummer, and after that every abelian extension is Kummer.

In positive characteristic, this does not work. Suppose that $F$ has characteristic $2$. Then $F$ does not admit a nontrivial primitive square root of unity. Thus if $\exp(A)$ is even, an $A$-Galois extension is not Kummer. For example, $\mathbb{F}_2 \to \mathbb{F}_4$ is not Kummer, and indeed, rather obviously, no extension of $\mathbb{F}_2$ is Kummer. If you start with $\mathbb{F}_4$, then you do admit cube roots of unity. So the cubic extensions $\mathbb{F}_4 \to \mathbb{F}_{4^3} \to \mathbb{F}_{4^{9}} \to \dots$ are all Kummer. On the other hand, $\mathbb{F}_{4^3}^\times$ has order $64-1 = 9\times 7$, and hence a 7th root of unity. So you get to do degree-7 extensions. $\mathbb{F}_{4^7}$ contains roots of order $43$ and $127$, and $\mathbb{F}_{4^{21}}$ also contains roots of order $337$ and $5419$. And so on.

For another example, start at $3$. Then $\mathbb{F}_3$ contains a primitive square root, and so all degree-$2$ extensions are Kummer.  $\mathbb{F}_{3^2}$ is no help: it contains an 8th root, but degree-$8$ extensions are compositions of degree-$2$ extensions. At the next step, though, $\mathbb{F}_{3^4}$ contains a $5$th root of unity, and $\mathbb{F}_{3^8}$ contains a $41$st root of unity. Once you do one degree-$5$ extension, you pick up an $11$th root of unity.

**Question 1:** Given a prime power $q = p^n$, which primes $\ell$ eventually appear as degrees of iterated Kummer extensions of $\mathbb{F}_q$? The answer is not "all of them other than $p$". Obviously $\ell = p$ does not. Go back to $q=4$. Then any $\mathbb{F}_{4^m}$ has only odd roots of unity, and so the only allowed $m$s are going to be odd. So a necessary condition for $\ell$ to appear is that $4^{m}-1$ is divisible by $\ell$ for odd $m$, equivalently for $4$ to have odd order mod $\ell$. But for example $4$ has even order mod $5$. So iterated Kummer extensions of $\mathbb{F}_4$ never include $5$th roots of unity. So $m$ is never divisible by $5$. But $4$ has order $5$ mod $31$. So $\ell = 31$ is also out.

**Question 2:** In the finite field case that I used for examples, all extensions are abelian. In general,  iterated Kummer extensions are solvable but not abelian. Every group $G$ has a universal solvable quotient — you quotient $G$ by its [perfect core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_core) (the limit of its derived series) — and dually every field $F$ has a universal solvable extension $F^{\mathrm{slv}}$. In characteristic zero, iterated Kummer extensions catch all roots of unity, and so $F \to F^{\mathrm{slv}}$ is iterated Kummer. What about in positive characteristic? The universal iterated-Kummer extension $F^{\mathrm{Kum}}$ is typically smaller than $F^{\mathrm{slv}}$. Who is it, and does it have a name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solvable extension is iterated Kummer if and only if for all primes $\ell$ dividing its degree, the extension adjoining the $\ell$th roots of unity is iterative Kummer.

Proof: For if, first adjoin the $\ell$th roots of unity for all the relevant $\ell$, then write the extension as a sequence of degree $\ell$ extensions, all of which are Kummer.

For only if, the only way an extension of degree a multiple of $\ell$ can be a Kummer extension of a field of degree not a multiple of $\ell$ is if the base field contains the $\ell$th roots of unity, so for an iterated Kummer extension to have a degree a multiple of $\ell$ there must be an iterated Kummer extension containing the $\ell$th roots of unity.

This gives an inductive characterization:

In particular, over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$, to see if a prime $\ell$ is allowed, look at the multiplicative order of $q$ mod $\ell$, take its prime factors, look at the multiplicative order of $q$ mod those primes, and iterate. If all iterations end up at $1$ then degree $\ell$ extensions are iterated Kummer. If some iteration ends up at the characteristic then they are not.

There doesn't seem likely to be a non-inductive characterization.