# When is $q$ invertible mod $m$, mod its order mod $m$, mod its order mod its order mod $m$, ad infinitum?

Tags: nt.number-theory, finite-fields

Fix an [edit: positive] integer $q$. Let me say that an [edit: positive] integer $m$ is *IK over $q$* if $q$ and $m$ are coprime and the (multiplicative) order of $q$ mod $m$ is IK over $q$. Note that that multiplicative order is strictly less than $m$, so the induction terminates.

Is there a non-inductive characterization of which $m$ are IK over $q$?

---

This question is a follow-up to my question about when a field extension is [iterative Kummer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461513/), hence the name "IK." In an answer, Will Sawin speculates that the answer to this question is "no," but it seems worth asking a wider audience.

---

Added in response to comment: The base of the induction is that $1$ is IK over $q$. When you unwrap the induction, it asks the following. Repeatedly replace $m \mapsto $ order of $q$ mod $m$. If you eventually get to $1$, then $m$ is IK over $q$. If you eventually get to a number not coprime to $q$, then $m$ is not IK over $q$.

Comment: I do not understand the definition. What is the base of this induction?

Comment: It seems that the base is "1 is IK over any q"

Comment: Please include some examples. It will make it more immediately clear what is going on.